# How do I take a vow of truth?

Tags: vrata, sankalpa, satyanarayana

I am looking for the mantra which contains the satyavrat, or the best way to take a vow of truth so as to receive the sankalpa of the lord, so that I can best uphold my vow. I have searched in many places, there were no answers. Due to circumstances of location etc. I have no person to ask. I looked at the vidhi of satyanarayana puja, there was no vow. Is the puja itself the vow? I am looking for the TRUE satyavrat. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to do the resolve (or what Sankalpa mantras to recite) before starting a puja or vrata?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. I am asking how to do the resolve, ie the sankalpa mantras and vidhi.

Comment: Ok no problem . I also guessed that you are asking about that only